# Is ISet not available in Mono?

Tags: c#, .net, mono

Is [ISet Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412081.aspx) available in Mono? I can't seem to find it.

EDIT: After setting Target Framework to 4.0 in MonoDevelop I am still getting the error:

> Error CS0246: The type or namespace name ISet could not be found. Are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Can anyone with Mono confirm if `ISet` works for them?

Comment: You have to target framework 4.0 for the `ISet` interface to be availabe.

Comment: How can I do that? I am using monodevelop fyi.

Comment: I've just set my projects to point to .NET - but I am still getting `...: Error CS0246: The type or namespace name ISet could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference? (CS0246) (FooBar.API)`

Comment: Firstly you have to target 4.0 framework or newer in MonoDevelop, secondly check you have System assembly in project references.

Comment: "check you have System assembly in project references" - how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You have to target framework 4.0 for the `ISet` interface to be availabe.

The interface is in the System.Collections.Generic namespace, so you either need to specify the full name `System.Collections.Generic.ISet` or have this using statement:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

According to the [Mono compatibility page](http://www.mono-project.com/Compatibility), Mono 2.10.8 supports everything in framework 4.0, except WPF, EntityFramework and WF, part of WCF.

Comment: I have `Runtime: Mono 2.10.8` and in my project `Target Framework` set to `Mono .NET 4.0`. And still get the error if I try to use `ISet`. Can you try it on yours and see if it works? Thanks!

Comment: @drozzy, I was able to target 4.0 with MonoDevelop and ISet is available.